# number of days gap in between 2 dates to include the resultant data as another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server how can we get days gap in between 2 dates (I am fetching these 2 dates from other two columns as `Sdate` and `EDate`). I want to include the resultant data as another column

```
CREATE TABLE Remaingdays1
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  SDate DATE,
  EDate Date,
  remaingdays as  SDate-EDate--   This should be the resultant of days
);
```

Comment: mysql and ms sql server are 2 different products. Pls use only the relevant product tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE Remaingdays1 ( id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    SDate DATE, EDate Date, 
    remaingdays as (datediff(day, sdate,edate)))
```

Comment: there are 2 bugs in computed column: 1 the type of remaingdays is missing and datediff has only 2 args: you can change it like this **remaingdays int AS (datediff(sdate,edate)));**

Comment: @BerndBuffen . . . Your comment is 200% incorrect -- both points are entirely wrong.

Comment: Syntax for datediff as per Microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql

Comment: Datatype derives based on highest datatype of return value, here it is INT by default...

Comment: @ all -- sorry !!!! -- i select only mysql questions and i did not seen that is sql server question